# nullmailer not changing outgoing address correctly

Tags: linux, debian, email

I have a bit of a weird problem. I have nullmailer set up on 3 different machines, 1 running Debian stable and 2 running Debian testing.

The config files on each machine are basically the same: `me+hostname@mydomain.com` in the file `adminaddr`, nothing in `defaultdomain` and ... well the login  details for my mail in `remotes`. However nullmailer isn't working on a single machine (one of the ones running Debian testing), the other 2 of them work fine!

If I try to send a test mail via `mail -s "Test" root@hostname < /dev/null` instead of sending it to `me+hostname@mydomain.com` `mail.log` tells me it's trying to send it to exactly what I tell the mail command: `root@hostname`. On the other 3 machines it's correctly sent to the address provided in `adminaddr`.

The version of nullmailer is 2.2-3, but I also tried 2.1-7~bpo9+1 and it didn't change anything.

Anyone have ideas for what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the hostname to `/etc/mailname` fixed it (the file was empty on the machine that it wasn't working on). :/